# How to rename chromosome_position column in a Beagle file and match it with the index fai?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, bioinformatics

I have text files (tab separated) which have different columns. I need to rename my `chromosome_position` column (see MM.beagle.gz file below) since a program that I use don't allow multiple underscores in the chromosome name (causing a parsing issue because `NC_044592.1_3795` is not working as a name).

My indexed genome looks like this:

```
head my.fna.fai
```

Contains this:

```
NC_044571.1     115307910       88      80      81
NC_044572.1     151975198       116749435       80      81
NC_044573.1     113180500       270624411       80      81
NC_044574.1     71869398        385219756       80      81
```

The bealgle file looks like this:

```
zcat MM.beagle.gz | head | cut -f 1-3
```

Which gives:

```
marker  allele1 allele2
NC_044571.1_3795        G       T
NC_044573.1_3796        G       T
NC_044572.1_3801        T       C
NC_044574.1_3802        G       A
```

In R I can get the chromosome and position:

```
beag = read.table("MM.beagle.gz", header = TRUE)
chr=gsub("_\\d+$", "", beag$marker)
pos=gsub("^[A-Z]*_[0-9]*.[0-9]_", "", beag$marker)
```

But I'm not able to rename the beagle file in-place. I'd like to rename all contigs in the `.fai` file from `1:nrow(my.fna.fai)` and match it to the beagle file.

So in the end the `.fai` should look like:

```
head my.fna.fai
```

Desired output:

```
1     115307910       88      80      81
2     151975198       116749435       80      81
3     113180500       270624411       80      81
4     71869398        385219756       80      81
```

And the beagle file:

```
zcat MM.beagle.gz | head | cut -f 1-3
```

Would give:

```
marker  allele1 allele2
1_3795        G       T
3_3796        G       T
2_3801        T       C
4_3802        G       A
```

where `22_3795` is the concatenation of the contig `22` and the position `3795`, separated with an `_`.

The solution would preferentially be in bash as R is not practical due to the large file size of my final compressed beagle file (>210GB)

Someone proposed to change the `.fai` with this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print NR, $2, $3, $4, $5}' my.fna.fai
```

What I'm not able to figure out now is to make sure that the `.fai` and the `.beagle` file are consistent with each other. For example, event if the first column (marker) of the `.beagle` file is shuffled, it should be possible to match it with the `.fai` file and rename the chromosome names in the `.beagle` file. For example, if `NC_1234.1` is renamed to `142` in the `.fai`, then all `NC_1234.1_XXX` in the `.beagle` should become `142_XXX`, where XXX are numbers.

Here is an attempt at the solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $1, NR}' my.fna.fai > my.fna.fai.nr

awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{split($1,a,"_"); print $0,a[1]"_"a[2],a[3]}' MM.beagle.txt | awk 'NR!=1 {print}' | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{print $0, NR}'> file2.sep.txt

sort file2.sep.txt > file2.1.s.txt

join -1 4 -2 1 file2.1.s.txt  my.fna.fai.nr | sort -k6 -n   | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$1=$2=$6="";print $7"_"$5,$0}' | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{$4=$5="";print $0}' > file4.txt
echo $(awk 'NR==1 {print}' MM.beagle.txt); cat file4.txt
```

Gives

```
marker allele1 allele2
1_3795  G       T
3_3796  G       T
2_3801  T       C
4_3802  G       A
```

Comment: Get rid of all the `...`s so we have sample input/output we can copy/paste to test with.

Comment: OK, I also separated the commands from the data.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9540765/

Comment: @Pierre, do you want me to delete one? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the new FASTA index and modified Beagle files are consistent, we can use the FASTA index and an associative array to store the chromosome name with it's line number. This lets us then parse the Beagle file and use the chromosome name to retrieve the line number from the array. Here's one way using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

Contents of `rename_chroms.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}

FNR==NR {
    arr[$1]=NR
    next
}

FNR==1 {
    print
    next
}

{
    n = split($1, a, "_")

    chrom = substr($1, 0, length($1) - (length(a[n]) + 1))
    pos = a[n]

    print arr[chrom] "_" pos, $2, $3
}
```

Run using:

```
awk -f rename_chroms.awk my.fna.fai <(zcat MM.beagle.gz)
```

Results:

```
marker  allele1 allele2
1_3795  G   T
2_3796  G   T
3_3801  T   C
4_3802  G   A
```

Comment: In my case, I needed the line `print arr[chrom] "_" pos, $2, $3` to be `print arr[chrom] "_" pos, $0`, but this works exactly as I was hoping! And it's much simpler than the convoluted way I tried in the question.